# Play unsupported games on low end devices(hack/tweak)

Tags: windows-10-mobile, store

I have a 512MB low end device(Nokia Lumia 720). I wish to play high-end games on it like Dead Trigger 2 and other Gameloft Games. But, the store says my device is incompatible.

I am an android user. Back in 2013 when we had low-end android device we use to change its `built.prop` file to trick PlayStore(android app store) and play high-end games like assassin's creed etc.

We use to change the dpi, ram, device's model, vendor and other kind of details so that PlayStore would think we are using a high-end device and would let us download the app.

Is there some sort of similar trick to play with Windows Store?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there some sort of similar trick to play with Windows Store?

This can be done by editing the registry in Windows 10 mobile. By editing the registry you can change your phone model. This method is not recomended but I am explaining it here as you have asked it.

---

### Warning

This can cause serious problems such as compatiblity issues and others. You should proceed at your own risk.

---

### Steps:

1. Go to *Settings->Update & Security->For developers*.
2. Enable devoleper mode.
   [image]
3. Download Interlop Tools from [here](https://mega.nz/#!rRMhEJgT!pPXGnGIT4DV6dip6JAOS_c1NSQv9cJ_hgKiWnGgbwKw).
4. After downloading the appx file install it on your phone.
5. You can find the Interlop tools in Settings->Extras->Interlop Tools
   [image]
6. Open the Registry Editor
7. Select Registry Hiva as *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*
8. Set Registry Key Path as *SYSTEM/Platform/DeviceTargetingInfo*
9. Change the PhoneManufacturerModelName to some other model value such as RM=938_1000
10. Now click Write Data.

---

**Note :** I have tried using Interlop tools but I have not edited such important registry settings. But some people have done this to install Windows 10 on unsupported mobiles. And they have no problem with it so far. I am saying this from their comments on the an [article](http://www.windowscentral.com/interop-tools-windows-10-mobile) about this tool.

> Thanks to reg editing, I have been using Redstone builds on my Icon for a month now.

---

### References

1. [Interop Tools for Windows 10 Mobile lets you edit your registry for some hacking fun - WindowsCentral](http://www.windowscentral.com/interop-tools-windows-10-mobile)
2. [Reg edit to add 5 actions button - forum.xda developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=62177822)

Comment: changing the manufacturer name , BSP release code, configuration id, device name etc, will only allow us to get updates, store doesn't change

Comment: but how to install xap file for Interlop? Should I move it to device via cable and then just touch it to install?

Comment: @AbhimanyuAryan Yes, you are correct. Move it to your phone. Open the locaion via File explorer and click on the xap file. But this has to be done after enabling the developer mode.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we can do that, i played a lot of games that are supported in 1 gb ram on my 520. i even played some paid games like NFS hot pursuit, NFS undercover, Mirror's edge, etc.

all you need is a pc with atleast win 8.1 and phone on 10.

- switch on developer option in settings.
- install 8.1sdk on your pc using ths [link](http://www.windowscommunity.in/download-windows-phone-8-1-sdk-lite/)
- Download patched games. click [here](http://winphonehub.org/windows-phone-512-ram-patched-games-working-list/) to some some 1gb ram games that are supported on 512mb devices, even san andreas is supported.
- download the xap/appx, deploy it to phone using the sdk while phone is connected to pc via usb cable.
- but using xap deployer is easyier than sdk, but xap deployer needs sdk to be installed on your pc for it to work, download xap deployer from [here](http://winphonehub.org/wp8-xap-deployer-2-0-pc-tool-deploy-wp8-xap-device/)

Comment: but how to install xap file. Should I move it to device via cable and then just touch it to install?

Comment: you can deploy appx as well as xap using 8.1 sdk on pc, and u dont need to move the file to phone, just connect your phone via usb cable, open 8.1 sdk, it will recognize your phone, just browse to the app path on pc and click deploy, thats it.

Comment: I am using Windows 10 so do I need Windows 10 sdk? Can you provide me with a guide how to deploy using SDK. I am not sure if that includes using visual studio or some other way :(

Comment: no, you will not be needing anything heavy, download n install 8.1 sdk lite(`100 mb) and xap deployer 2.0 (1mb) from above links.

Answer (score -1):

Registry editing method is not really safe.But i have seen some developers using this tricks.But frankly speaking its not successful for me.
Best part is to download games from third-party websites and deploy it using sd cards and deploying tools.

Comment: You have linked to that same site in several answers now. Please take a look at [this Help Center article](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) and consider whether the link is actually relevant to the original question. Also, if you're affiliated with that site, you have to disclose this fact in your posts.